# how to dynamically update svg using Raphael?

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I'm trying to write something to simplify experimentation with SVG path, but i have a problem where it doesn't actually update the screen when i can verify that the svg code is updated. Basically the work flow is as follows: I type something into the input box (A path string), and click draw, it will clear the canvas, then draw the shape according to the typed path string.

After some more testing, i realized that it seem to be a bug in beta chrome. As the following code seem to work fine in firefox. If anyone have any insights, it would be much appreciated!

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var paper = Raphael($('#paper')[0], 500, 500);
  $('#path').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    var rect = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    console.log(rect);
    var path = paper.path($(this).val());
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="paper"></div>
  <div id="pathDiv">
    <input id="path" type="text" name="path" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone have any suggestions, it would be much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem you're experiencing is that you're writing a new path each time you execute your `onchange` function, whereas what you really want to do is update your existing path.  To do this take the declarations for `rect` and `path` outside of your event handler function, then update the existing objects inside the function like this:

```
var paper = Raphael($('#paper')[0], 500, 500);
var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
var path = paper.path("M100,25 L100,140 L50,50");

$('#path').change(function(){
  rect.attr({x: "10", y: "10"});
  path.attr("path",$(this).val());
});
```

I've [tried this](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/dynamic.html) in Firefox and IE and it seems to work fine.  If this isn't what you meant please update your question.

Comment: Hey, i clarified the question to include hopefully more information regarding what i want to do.

Comment: @FurtiveFelon OK, I think the example I've linked will do what you want, except without recreating the SVG every time.  Just take the rect element out (and probably make the text input bigger).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine now in chrome. Result can be seen here: http://svgpath.com/